# How can I avoid a nested form situation?

Tags: asp.net, forms, visual-studio, master-pages

Ok basically I have a master page which has all the design in a Form with runat server as follows:

```
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <table style="font-family: Arial">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="width: 800px; height: 80px; background-color: #3399FF; text-align: center">
          <h1>WebSite Header
          </h1>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 500px; background-color: #66FFFF; width: 150px">
          <h3>Menu</h3>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 500px; background-color: #9999FF; width: 650px">
          <h3>content</h3>
          <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
              <p>
                &nbsp;</p>
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="background-color: #3399FF; text-align: center">
          <b>Website Footer</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I am trying to do a page using this master page and in this page I am initializing a CKEditor which apparently needs to be in a form with runat server to be able to function, as follows:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CkEditor.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.CkEditor" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

  <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <div>
      <div>
        <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" runat="server">
        </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
      </div>
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
      <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" Text=" "></asp:Label>
    </div>
  </form>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

The Form however with the CKEditor in it is not allowing to be initialized because it is becoming a Nested Form, since the master page itself is bound in a form.

How  can I prevent this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CKEditorControl` will inherit the form from the master page.

First, move your `asp:ContentPlaceHolder` from the `head` tag:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<!--DON'T PUT IT HERE-->
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
      </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
...
```

Now you can remove the `form2`:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<!--<form id="form2" runat="server">-->
  <div>
    <div>
      <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" runat="server">
      </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
...
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Really appreciate your help